# How to Print Pattern Shown?

Tags: python

How do I print pattern in python as shown below:

**My code:**

```
for outer_loop in reversed(range(1, 5+1)):
    for inner_loop in range(0,outer_loop):
#         print(inner_loop*' ')
        print('*',end='')
    print()
```

**Output:**

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

I want to give spaces on left side as shown below,

**Expected Output:**

```
*****
 ****
  ***
   **
    *
```

Comment: So print spaces in a loop before the `*` loop.

Comment: If you know how to print N asterisks, why can't you figure out how to print 5-N spaces before it?

Comment: Please post answer, accordingly !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a method `rjust` on strings:

```py
for n in range(5, 0, -1):
  print( (n*"*").rjust(5) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `reversed()`, `range()` can return a reversed range by using a negative step.

You can multiply a string to duplicate it, instead of using a loop.

Add the spaces by printing `5 - n` spaces before `n` asterisks.

```
for n in range(5, 0, -1):
    print(" " * (5-n) + "*" * n)
```